# Assembler команды перессылки

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Правильно ли выполнены первые 5 условий?
Изучаю ассемблер, не могу понять как реализовать 6-е условие, где об этом можно прочесть?

[image: tasm]

```
data segment 
p1350       dw  -1350
p13     dd  -1313131313
p156    db  156
data ends
stk segment stack
    db  256 dup ("?")
stk ends
code segment 
main proc
    assume cs:code, ds:data, ss:stk
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    xor ax, ax
    mov bp, 1345h
    mov dx, bp
    mov cx, bp
    mov cx, ax
    mov ax, p156
    mov si, 1350h
    push word ptr p13
    push word ptr p13+2
    pop word ptr p13
    pop word ptr p13+2
    xchg ah, cl
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
code ends
end main
```

Comment: Добавьте текст задания текстом, а не изображением. У вас же он в браузере открыт - скопируйте и вставьте в вопрос, потом отформатируйте списком. То же самое с кодом программы - скопируйте и вставьте, потом выделите и нажмите на кнопку `{}` в редакторе вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Пункт 2 - по заданию нужно отрицательное число, у вас положительное
- Пункт 5: двухбайтовый регистр `CX` состоит из двух байтовых (`CH` - старший байт, `CL` - младший байт), регистр `AX` - аналогично (из регистров `AH` и `AL`). Теперь перечитайте задание, и поймете что куда нужно положить
- Пункт 6. РОН - регистр общего назначения. Используйте любой из регистров AX, CX, DX, не ошибетесь. По поводу регистра BX - это регистр базы, как и регистры BP, SP, т.е. может использоваться в качестве базового регистра в адресации вида `[bx+di]` так же как и `[bp+di]`, например. Регистры SI, DI - индексные регистры, могут использоваться, например, в качестве индекса при выборе элемента из массива. Все эти регистры входят в список регистров общего назначения.
- Пункт 7 - с помощью инструкции `push` кладем младшую и старшую части переменной p13 на стек, забираем с помощью команды `pop` в таком порядке, чтобы они поменялись местами. Основное свойство стека (как структуры данных) - то что последний добавленный в него элемент снимается первым (LIFO - Last In - First Out). Аналогия - стопка тарелок, можно класть только сверху, снимать тоже только сверху. В принципе в стек можно писать напрямую, но инструкции `push` и `pop` как раз работают со стеком как со "стопкой" объектов (собственно, staсk и переводится как стопка).
- Пункт 8 - см. про пункт 5, с тем дополнением, что для обмена (а не просто замены) в простейшем случае нужно использовать дополнительный регистр.

Comment: Залил изменения, сейчас появилась ошибка: http://imgur.com/a/6vA6D

Comment: @user234223, 19 строка - в 2-байтовый регистр записываете значение из 1-байтовой переменной. Ошибки в 20, 21 строках - ругается на неизвестный символ ptr13. В тексте программы я этого не вижу. Конкретно по pop/push на tasm не могу сказать насколько верно реализовано. Для fasm выглядело бы примерно так`push word [p13]`, `push word [p13+2]`, `pop word [p13]`, `pop word [p13+2]`.